# Cloud Function CPUMilliSeconds quota exceeded

Tags: go, google-cloud-functions, serverless-framework, google-cloud-run

I've noticed a substantial number in my golang Cloud Function errors:

```
Error: quota exceeded (Quota exceeded for quota group 'CPUMilliSeconds' and limit 'CPU allocation in function invocations for us-central1 per 100 seconds' of service
```

What strange, is that  I have no more than 60 invocations per second with 30 active instances cloud function running at the peak.

I understand that is that you can have a max of 1,000 concurrent instances, which in my case 30 is far cry to hit CPU limit.

[Cloud function quota here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas)

What is the best way to control Cloud Function CPU execution ?

Would you recommend using CloudRun instead of Cloud Functions for some more CPU "demanding task"?

Comment: I've never seen that message before, but Cloud Functions is definitely not intended to be used for computationally demanding operations.  Neither is Cloud Run for that matter.  I'd look into Compute Engine for that.

Comment: The same here, Iespecially that CF is only given one virtual cpu

Comment: What's the workload? What are you doing in that GCF?

Comment: Simple data transformation and compression

Answer (score 3):

One of the quota limits of Google Cloud Functions is [GHz-seconds](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#rate_limits) which means the total amount of CPU seconds consumed by all running functions, the error you see is raised when you're reach that quota during a 100s time frame. Since your function is carrying a computationally intensive workload it's easier to reach the limit.

As for how to control CPU usage the only way would be to delay your requests to keep your usage below these limits. The alternative would be giving less [memory](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing#compute_time) to the function which in turn will be counterproductive because your functions will span longer time and you might run in the same trouble anyway.

As Doug pointed out Cloud Functions are not intended for your use case and neither Cloud Run. GCE instances are better for computationally intensive operations as there are no memory limitations but the amount you have provided, they also allow to run containerized code in an Container Optimized OS.

Hope this helps.